# Getting error while using new JParameter($plugin->params); in joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla3.0

I have used the following code in joomla 3.0 for getting plugin parameters.

```
new JParameter($plugin->params);
```

But I am getting error.

Please any one can help me.

Regards,
Jaylani.

Comment: you need to provide the error if you expect some sort of help ;)

Comment: try using `JForm` instead of `JParameter` as I think this was deprecated in Joomla 2.5

Comment: Lodder is correct ... JParameter was deprecated for all of 1.6-2.5 and removed in J3.

Comment: I have tried with Jform instead of JParameter, but its not working.Any other solution to cure this issue

Comment: what does your error log say?

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Accessing_Component_Parameters_in_the_Front-end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JParameter was using JRegistry, here is a work around:

```
$params = new JRegistry();
$params->loadString($module->params);

$params->get('param_name');
```

Answer (score 3):

Removed classes

- JParameter (use JForm instead or, in most circumstances, JRegistry - for example to retrieve in a component a plugin parameter).

[Source](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1)

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but for everyone else who stumbles upon this:

Use:

```
json_decode($plugin->params);
```

I found this along with lots of other useful informations about the changes in Joomla 3.0 here: [techjoomla.com](http://techjoomla.com/joomla-development/joomla-30-conversion-changes-needed-when-converting-a-common-installable-package-for-joomla-15x-a-25x-to-joomla-30.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead of JParameter (deprecated class in J3):

```
jimport('joomla.html.parameter');
$params = new JInput();
$params->get('params');
```

This might answer your question and solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

JParameter is deprecated use Registry.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\PluginHelper;
use Joomla\Registry\Registry;

$plugin    = PluginHelper::getPlugin('plg_Type', 'plg_Name');
$plgParams = new Registry($plugin->params);

$param     = $plgParams->get('your_param_name', 'default_value')
```